# BizTalk Error: "...Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema for the operation."

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

The following error has been occurring recently in BizTalk and I have had no joy in troubleshooting the error myself:

```
The start element with name "TypedPollingResultSet0" and namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/BadgeMaker" was unexpected. Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema for the operation.
```

The message that is causing the error has no orchestration and is solely done on ports. The receive port polls a SQL Server stored procedure and the schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/BadgeMaker" xmlns:ns0="https://BadgeMaker.bagemaker_properties" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/BadgeMaker" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">TypedPolling.BadgeMaker</fileNameHint>
      <schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
      <b:imports>
        <b:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="https://BadgeMaker.bagemaker_properties" location=".\bagemaker_properties.xsd" />
      </b:imports>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType name="TypedPollingResultSet0">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MiFare" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Expiry" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Student_id" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="TypedPollingResultSet0" nillable="true" type="tns:TypedPollingResultSet0">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:properties>
          <b:property name="ns0:PersonID" xpath="/*[local-name()='TypedPollingResultSet0' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/BadgeMaker']/*[local-name()='ID' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/BadgeMaker']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfTypedPollingResultSet0">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TypedPollingResultSet0" type="tns:TypedPollingResultSet0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfTypedPollingResultSet0" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfTypedPollingResultSet0" />
  <xs:element name="TypedPolling">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">TypedPolling</doc:action>
        <doc:description xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">exec MiFareNotification</doc:description>
      </xs:documentation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='TypedPolling' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/BadgeMaker']/*[local-name()='TypedPollingResultSet0' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/BadgeMaker']" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TypedPollingResultSet0" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfTypedPollingResultSet0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The "bagemaker" schema imported in this schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://BadgeMaker.bagemaker_properties" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="https://BadgeMaker.bagemaker_properties" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="property" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="lost_card_type" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="bc02fae8-bcf7-4223-b78f-85d77f7153ac" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="PersonID" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="facb4c50-c234-4824-bd05-be27aaa35ef7" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is then mapped to a send port which is bound to another SQL Server stored procedure.

The map is as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsGKA.jpg

The schema for sending to the stored procedure is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">TypedProcedure.dbo</fileNameHint>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="sp">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">TypedProcedure/dbo/sp</doc:action>
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Mifare" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Expiry" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="sp">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">TypedProcedure/dbo/sp/response</doc:action>
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReturnValue" type="xs:int" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I can't see any issue with the ports, the stored procedures or the schemas themselves; everything seems to match up to me. If I've missed any information out then please let me know. I have checked existing similar questions and forum posts but haven't found anything that stands out as applicable.

Comment: Hi Jevi.  At this point I would usually re-generate the Polling schema in Visual Studio, and then either compare the newly generated files with the existing to see what the different is. The other option is re-create the receive port from the bindings it creates when you regenerate.

Comment: I've re-generated the schema as you suggested and it's still throwing the same error, quoting the name of the old schema but I can't see where else it's used. I've restarted the host instance etc and everything is pointed to the new schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error looks like on the send port, correct? And it complaints about a TypedPollingResultSet0, that sounds like the schema from your receive location. So my suspicion is that your message is not being mapped to your final schema.

Also make sure you check if you property promote the BTS.Operation on your send port, or as an alternative, place the operation value directly into the action field.

Finally, you can track your messages and let us know what really is going on based on the message properties at the receive and send side.

Comment: My send port is configured as follows: https://imgur.com/a/aPZ7N1L I can't see any issue with this or the schemas I mentioned in my original post and everything lines up with the related stored procedures

Comment: @jevi enable tracking and analyse the last few tracked events at the send port.

Comment: @jevi also enable tracking on the pipeline artifacts you are using.

Comment: Just noticed that the namespace quoted in the error message isn't a namespace used by either schema on the send port, nor is it used anywhere else. Not sure why this is?

Comment: @jevi so there are always 2 namespaces for a schema. This is probably the target namespace (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/technical-reference/target-namespace-node-property-of-all-schemas). Is it still not one you recognize?

Comment: So, as a timeline of events here, I started receiving this error and then recreated the schemas and maps to make sure they were correct. For some reason, the schema strong name attached to the message I see in the console is that of the old schema. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @jevi because it's still deployed maybe. Check all schemas deployed in the admin console. Maybe it's in another application.

Comment: The schema is used elsewhere, but not in anything to do with where the error is coming from; could the port named in the error be a red herring?

Comment: @jevi read about specifying the InboundID, it should be the same in the SQL URI as in the schema itself.

Comment: Thanks! The issue was with the InboundID; everything works as intended now

Comment: @javi glad you figured it out!